# Getting a String from a list of strings

Tags: string-manipulation, concatenation

Is there a way to write down `Mathematica` with a string such as:
`{"M","a","t","h","e","m","a","t","i","c","a"}`?

Comment: `?*String*` will list the available string functions if you need more information.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Supporting the maxim "there is always another way to do it":

```
list = {"M","a","t","h","e","m","a","t","i","c","a"};
```

`StringJoin` accepts lists directly, and in fact is faster this way:

```
StringJoin @ list
```

> ```
> "Mathematica"
> ```

Also, `StringJoin` has the short form `<>` therefore you could also use:

```
"" <> list
```

> ```
> "Mathematica"
> ```

Speed check:

```
large = Characters@ExampleData[{"Text", "LoremIpsum"}];

Do[StringJoin @@ large, {5000}] // Timing

Do[StringJoin @ large, {5000}]  // Timing

Do["" <> large, {5000}]         // Timing
```

Version 7.0.1 timings:

> ```
> {1.622, Null}
>
> {0.702, Null}
>
> {0.718, Null}
> ```

Version 10.1.0 timings:

> ```
> {0.6864, Null}
>
> {0.4524, Null}
>
> {0.4524, Null}
> ```

Comment: ""<> list ...Elegant!

Comment: @Öskå Jagra's answer shows something else: it would still work if `StringJoin` could *only* accept two strings.  `Fold` is a very useful function to know.  See my example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5838577/618728).

Comment: @Jagra thanks :D

Comment: Brilliant. I definitely need to get used with # and @@ and & and such things, is there a good "course" about this on S.E.?

Comment: @Öskå for those operators specifically [Pure Functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/PureFunctions.html) and [Applying Functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ApplyingFunctionsToListsAndOtherExpressions.html) are a good start.  There is a lot of good information in the Documentation Center (in the Help menu) once you learn to navigate it.  Be sure to notice the links at the bottom of the page such as *Virtual Book*, *How-to topics*, *First steps with Mathematica*, etc.  [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) is useful for basic questions.

Comment: Thanks! Ive also downloaded LeonidShifrin's book like a day ago, I'vent found much ways to learn more than basics. Is his book a good start?

Comment: @Öskå yes, Leonid's book will take you well beyond the basics, yet it is reasonably approachable.  A good choice!  Plus, he's right here on the site so you can ask for clarification of anything written.

Comment: It's a shame that you give the nice answer `StringJoin @ list`, but then use the not-so-nice answer `StringJoin @@ list` in your speed comparison.

Comment: @Carl Clearly a mistake; I'll correct it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Just for something different `Fold` works too:

```
Fold[#1 <> #2 &, "", {"M", "a", "t", "h", "e", "m", "a", "t", "i", 
  "c", "a"}]

"Mathematica"
```

Answer (score 9):

Use `StringJoin`:

```
StringJoin @@ {"M", "a", "t", "h", "e", "m", "a", "t", "i", "c", "a"}
```

> "Mathematica"

Comment: ah, been looking for one hour. *Feels dumb* Thanks!

Comment: No problem, we've all experienced the same thing, good luck.

Answer (score 7):

If we're going to get silly about it:

```
TextRecognize @ Graphics @ MapIndexed[Text[Style[#1, 50], {#2[[1]], 0}] &, list]
```

Answer (score 5):

At risk of taking "**even more**" *too far* here is a method that does not use any function with "String" in the name:

```
list = {"M", "a", "t", "h", "e", "m", "a", "t", "i", "c", "a"};

FromCharacterCode @ Flatten @ ToCharacterCode @ list
```

Or using an export function:

```
ExportString[{list}, "Table", "FieldSeparators" -> ""]
```

Or a formatting function:

```
ToString @ Row @ list
```

Comment: Sheer vulpinism, that's what it is :)

Comment: +1 for: 'ToString @ Row @ list'.  This seems to me the most interesting of all the solutions offered for the question, because you've taken such an original view of the problem while maintaing your customary clarity and conciseness.  Nice!

Answer (score 4):

Just to stretch **even more** the limits of "*there is always another way to do it*" (Mr.Wizard), here is a way to NOT use `StringJoin` at all:

```
chars = {"M", "a", "t", "h", "e", "m", "a", "t", "i", "c", "a"};
Fold[StringInsert[#1, #2, -1] &, "", Flatten@chars]
```

> ```
> "Mathematica"
> ```

And a simpler one:

```
StringExpression @@ chars
```

Using built-in path functions to complicate things (use `ToFileName` if prior to version 7):

```
StringReplace[FileNameJoin@chars, "\\" -> ""]
```

Answer (score 4):

In versions 10.1+, there is also [`StringRiffle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringRiffle.html):

```
StringRiffle[list, ""]
```

> "Mathematica"