# How to 'merge' a list like FromDigits, but with a mixture of numbers and symbols?

Tags: list-manipulation, concatenation

How do I go from `{C,4,G,5,S,7}` to `C4G5S7`

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7063/121

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If no elements of that list have values assigned:

```
Symbol @ ToString @ Row @ {C, 4, G, 5, S, 7}
```

> ```
> C4G5S7
> ```

If values *are* assigned add `HoldForm`, and if making a function add attribute `HoldAll`:

```
SetAttributes[merge, HoldAll]
merge[expr_List] := Symbol @ ToString @ HoldForm @ Row @ expr

G=1; S=2;

{C, 4, G, 5, S, 7} // merge
```

> ```
> C4G5S7
> ```

If one wants strings instead of symbols just leave out `Symbol`.

---

This method relies upon the particular behavior of formatting wrappers, Forms and how `ToString` handles them.

`Row` and `HoldForm` both act as wrappers for an expression.  `HoldForm` additionally holds its arguments.  Observe using `InputForm` (yet another wrapper) that both heads remain in the output:

```
HoldForm @ Row @ {1 + 1, 2 + 2} // InputForm
```

> ```
> HoldForm[Row[{1 + 1, 2 + 2}]]
> ```

However, in `StandardForm` (output in a Notebook) or `OutputForm` (output for terminals and text formats) these wrappers are not printed.  In the FrontEnd they affect the BoxData that is ultimately displayed.

As the documentation states:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Therefore `ToString @ HoldForm[Row[{1 + 1, 2 + 2}]]` yields:

> ```
> "1 + 12 + 2"
> ```

And `ToString[HoldForm[Row[{1 + 1, 2 + 2}]], StandardForm]` yields:

> ```
> "1+12+2"
> ```

Answer (score 5):

```
   ToExpression@StringJoin@(ToString /@ {C, 4, G, 5, S, 7})
   (* C4G5S7 *)
```

Comment: Any reason you don't use `Symbol`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, the usual reason: that it didn't occur to me:)

Comment: Actually now that I think about it in this simple construct my objection to `ToExpression` is probably meaningless.  Never mind, and +1.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, `Symbol` is already used in your answer, and, in combination with `Row`, makes a better answer than mine. Simon, if this were my question I would have accepted Mr.Wizard's answer :)

Comment: Yours however is a straightforward and easy to understand approach, whereas mine relies upon the "weird" behavior of formatting wrappers (which I should probably remark upon, come to think of it).

Answer (score 0):

```
StringReplace[ToString[#], Except[WordCharacter] :> ""] & /@ {{C, 4, 
   G, 5, S, 7}, {2, A, 4, B, 6, C, 0}, {0, A, 1, B, 2.1, 0}}
```

> => {C4G5S7, 2A4B6C0, 0A1B210}

or

```
StringReplace[# /. b_ :> ToString[b], 
   Except[WordCharacter] :>  ""] &@{C, 4, G, 5, S, 7}
```

> => C4G5S7

Notice that the first position of the list may be zero (