# How to joint symbolic expressions together

Tags: syntax, symbols, concatenation

I want to joint symbolic expressions together to create a another symbolic expressions.

one way to do that is as follows:

```
symb = ToExpression[ToString[#1] <> ToString[#2]] & @@@ {{x, y}, {y, 
    z}, {x, z}}

(*{xy, yz, xz}*)
```

is there any better way to do this? something like the StringJoin "<>" for strings

Comment: You may want to look at `SymbolName` and `Symbol`, but I think you are going to have to use string functions as you have done in your example.

Comment: So, what will the result of joining `Sin[x]` with `1+x+x^2` ? It can not be `Sin[x] 1 +x +x^2`  ?  Is that what you really want? May be there is need to add `( )` around each expression then before joining. However, there is issue where M sometimes removes those `( )` around single expression as not needed. Try typing `(x)` in the notebook, the result will be `x` as the `()` are stripped off. I think the semantics of joining expressions needs more thought.

Comment: `Symbol[SymbolName@# ~~ SymbolName@#2] & @@@ {{x, y}, {y, z}, {x, z}}`?

Comment: @Nasser that is not what I want. I want to create symbols from symbols in my work. but for your example, will be neat to create Sin from S,i,n?

Comment: It seems we've been down this road before: [How to 'merge' a list like FromDigits, but with a mixture of numbers and symbols?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20412) -- I shall mark this question as a duplicate unless someone disagrees.

Comment: OK, but you did say `joint symbolic expressions together`. And `Sin[x]` and `1 +x +x^2` are symbolic expressions. So that is why I asked. No problem.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard yes it is some thing similar. but again, converting to string and back to expression is the trick. not single join function for symbols yet.

Answer (score 1):

A bit more terse than your own code:

```
Symbol /@ ToString /@ Row /@ {{x, y}, {y, z}, {x, z}}
```

> ```
> {xy, yz, xz}
> ```

Or using `SymbolName` as suggested by [mfvonh](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5059/mfvonh) in the comments:

```
Symbol[""<>(SymbolName /@ #)] & /@ {{x, y}, {y, z}, {x, z}}
```

> ```
> {xy, yz, xz}
> ```

However, both these and yours will fail if a Symbol such as `x` already has a value.
To get around that you will need to introduce holding somewhere, perhaps like this:

```
SetAttributes[symbolJoin, HoldAll]

symbolJoin[s__Symbol] := Symbol @ ToString @ HoldForm @ Row[{s}]
```

Now:

```
x = 7;

List @@ symbolJoin @@@ Hold[{x, y}, {y, z}, {x, z}]
```

> ```
> {xy, yz, xz}
> ```

Or:

```
symbolJoin @@@ Unevaluated[{{x, y}, {y, z}, {x, z}}]
```

> ```
> {xy, yz, xz}
> ```