# Generating plot legends

Tags: plotting, legending

I want to generate a list as below for the legend of my plot,

```
{D=0, D=0.5, D=1, ...}
```

using the code

```
Table["D="  defocus, {defocus, Range[0, 3, 0.5]}]
```

However, it returns me the following,

> ```
> {0., 0.5 "D=", 1. "D=", 1.5 "D=", 2. "D=", 2.5 "D=", 3. "D="}
> ```

How could I fix this problem?
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: `Table["D=" <> ToString[defocus], {defocus, Range[0, 3, 0.5]}]`

Comment: BTW you can leave away the `Range` function and just use the numbers.

Comment: Thank you. Now I see why my code doesn't work.

Comment: Related: [(20412)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20412/121)

Comment: Thank you so much for showing me this thread

Answer (score 5):

Use `Row` to build the legend text.

```
funcs = Table[With[{k = k}, k # &], {k, 0, 3, 1/2}];
legends = Table[Row[{"D = ", N @ k}], {k, 0, 3, 1/2}];
Plot[Evaluate @ Through[funcs[x]], {x, 0, 5}, PlotLegends -> legends]
```

[image: plot]