# Some challenge for a Table mixing between output number Variables and ToString symbols

Tags: string-manipulation, list-manipulation, data, variable

How can I output a series of data, ranging from s00, s01, s02, s10, s11, s12, s20, s21, s22; by writing a table with s is a fixed, and m and n are running parameters, for example:

```
Table[ToString[smn], {m,0,2},{n,0,2}] ?
```

This above command fails, because it outputs something that I don't aim for:

```
{{0,0,0},{0,s,2 s},{0,2 s,4 s}}
```

but I wish to have an output like:

```
{{s00, s01, s02}, {s10, s11, s12}, {s20, s21, s22}}
```

So how should I modify my Table?

Comment: wonderich, I think this question could be considered a duplicate of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20412/121 e.g. `Table[ToString @ Row @ {s, m, n}, {m, 0, 2}, {n, 0, 2}]`.  Please let me know if you agree.

Comment: In addition,  `smn` is a single symbol.

Comment: Thank you everyone,  m_goldberg gives a much easier answer that seems to be appropriate for others to follow. So it is valuable to keep m_goldberg 's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two minor variations on your code will do it.

```
Table[StringJoin["s", ToString /@ {m, n}], {m, 0, 2}, {n, 0, 2}]
```

or

```
Table["s" <> ToString[m] <> ToString[n], {m, 0, 2}, {n, 0, 2}]
```

Both produce

> `{{"s00", "s01", "s02"}, {"s10", "s11", "s12"}, {"s20", "s21", "s22"}}`