# How to use a variable within StringJoin

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I would like Mathematica to symbolically line up partial derivative symbol with a value stored in variable.  I wrote this simple code below

```
x = 2*z;
StringJoin["∂", x, "/∂y"]
```

Comment: `StringJoin["\[PartialD]", ToString@x, "/ \[PartialD]y"]`

Comment: Related: [(10990)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10990/121), [(20412)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20412/121)

Comment: Lookup StringTemplate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x = 2 z;
```

Well you might write

```
StringJoin["∂(", ToString@x, ")/∂y"]
```

> `"∂(2 z)/∂y"`

which appears in an output cell as

[image: out1]

but I think you should consider

```
Row[{"∂(", x, ")/∂y"}]
```

> `Row[{"∂(", 2 z, ")/∂y"}]`

This appears in an output cell as

[image: out2]

Even though its internal form is very different from the string returned by `StringJoin`, its output form is very similar. I like `Row` because it does a better job of spacing the `2 z` term.

Comment: this is perfect!

Comment: @PatStarks. I'm glad you find my answer useful. Please consider accepting it. You can do that by clicking on the check mark that appears on the left of the answer below the down arrow.

Comment: ok thanks for telling me about the check mark!  I did not know about that.