# How to switch from array to string?

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, string-manipulation, concatenation

Considering we have an array:

```
a = {2/3, 4/5, 9/7, 3/7, 1/7, 1/9};
```

How can I get this to be:

```
"2/3 4/5 9/7 3/7 1/7 1/9"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Related: [(7063)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7063/121),
[(15032)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15032/121),
[(20412)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20412/121),
[(56419)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56419/121)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I would love this to be uniform for both integer and rational numbers

```
a2 = {2/3, 4/5, 9/7, 3/7, 1.5, 3, 1/9};


StringTrim@StringJoin[" " <> ToString[#, InputForm] & /@ a2]
(* 2/3 4/5 9/7 3/7 1.5 3 1/9 *)

Row[ToString[#, InputForm] & /@ a2, "  "]
(* 2/3  4/5  9/7  3/7  1.5  3  1/9 *)

StringReplace[ToString[a, InputForm], {"{" | "}" -> "", "," -> " "}]
(* 2/3  4/5  9/7  3/7  1.5  3  1/9 *)

StringJoin[Riffle[ToString[#, InputForm] & /@ a2, " "]]
(* 2/3 4/5 9/7 3/7 1.5 3 1/9 *)
```

Answer (score 4):

Or

```
StringTake[ToString[a, FormatType -> InputForm], {2, -2}]
```

The inelegant use of `StringTake` strips off the leading and trailing brackets.

Comment: Elegant! You can use `StringDelete[..., "{" | "}" | ","]` instead of `StringTake`.

Comment: Nice. Btw,  this does not give the same form the OP wanted due the "," being there between the numbers. May be just need small modification?

Comment: *May be just need small modification?* -- Surely, but left as an exercise for the reader :-)

Comment: Nice to see you here @HighPerformanceMark ! :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
a = {2/3, 4/5, 9/7, 3/7, 1/7, 1/9};
StringJoin@Cases[a, Rational[x_, y_] :> 
   " "<>ToString[x] <> "/" <> ToString[y]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Reply to comment "I would love this to be uniform for both integer and rational numbers":

```
a = {2/3, 4/5, 9/7, 3/7, 1/7, 1/9, 5, 6, 99/10};
f[Rational[x_, y_]] := " " <> ToString[x] <> "/" <> ToString[y];
f[x_] := " " <> ToString[x];
StringJoin[f[#] & /@ a]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I would love this to be uniform for both integer and rational numbers. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Terse:

```
a = {1, 17, 2/3, 4/5, 9/7, 3/7, 1/7, 1/9};

ToString @ Row[InputForm /@ a, " "]
```

> ```
> "1 17 2/3 4/5 9/7 3/7 1/7 1/9"
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Yet another possibility:

```
a = {2/3, 4/5, 9/7, 3/7, 1/7, 1/9, 5, 6, 99/10};
ExportString[{a}, "Table", "FieldSeparators" -> " "]
   "2/3 4/5 9/7 3/7 1/7 1/9 5 6 99/10"
```