# How to split list to strings?

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

Considering a list:

```
lst = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"}
```

How can I have two strings :

```
str1 = "1, 2, 3"
str2 = "4, 5, 6"
```

Thanks!

Comment: `str1 = StringJoin @@ lst[[ ;; 3]]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 StringTake[ToString@#, {2, -2}] & /@ Partition[lst, 3]
```

> ```
> {"1, 2, 3", 
>  "4, 5, 6"}
> ```

Answer (score 7):

```
lst = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"};
Developer`PartitionMap[StringTrim[ToString@#, "{" | "}"] &, lst, 3]
(* {"1, 2, 3", "4, 5, 6"} *)
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you always want strings with 3 items:

```
Map[StringJoin @@ Riffle[#, ", "] &, Partition[Map[ToString, lst], 3]]
```

Answer (score 5):

This is very similar to [your previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/79663/121) and so is the solution:

```
lst = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"}

ToString @ Row[#, ", "] & /@ Partition[lst, 3]
```

> ```
> {"1, 2, 3", "4, 5, 6"}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

This gives **exactly** the output you wrote down:

```
str1 = StringDrop[StringDrop[ToString@Partition[lst, 3][[1]], 1], -1]
str2 = StringDrop[StringDrop[ToString@Partition[lst, 3][[2]], 1], -1]
```

Could be made more elegant of course, and more flexible.

---

**EDIT** to make it more elegant:

```
TableForm[StringJoin /@ Partition[lst, 3]]
```

for display without the commas.

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"};

{str1, str2} = StringRiffle[#, ", "] & /@ Partition[list, 3];

str1
```

"1, 2, 3"

```
str2
```

"4, 5, 6"

Answer (score 1):

**Using `TextString`:**

```
Clear["Global`*"];
lst = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"};
t = TakeDrop[lst, Floor[ Length@lst /2]];
{str1, str2} = TextString[#, ListFormat -> {"", ", ", ""}] & /@ t
```

> {"1, 2, 3", "4, 5, 6"}